# FilenetP8 perfromance monitoring parameter

Tags: content-management-system, filenet-p8

I am new to Filenet and in my current project I have to find Filenet's performance monitoring parameters.

How we can access those parameters?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have much experience with FileNet P8 but do you have access to the system Dashboard ? It gives a huge amount of information about the performance of different applications of P8. 
Here's a link to the documentation :

https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSNW2F_5.2.1/com.ibm.p8.sysoverview.doc/p8sov135.htm

Comment: Thanks Alot , i read about this tool, but i need some java API for fetching those performance parameter

Answer (score 0):

The monitoring API is provided in 5.0.0.1 <-- FIX PACK 1 and later.

Read the release notes as this is the one case where you need to uninstall the existing product before installing the fixpack.